# removing the duplicates of a linked list javascript

Tags: javascript, class, linked-list, duplicates

This is my code so far comparing the nodes to each other:

```
const removeDuplicates = (headNode) => { 
  let cur = headNode;
  while (cur.next) {
    let nextnode = cur.next;
    if (cur.data == nextnode.data) {
      cur.next = cur.next.next;
    } else {
      cur = cur.next;    
    }
  }
  return headNode;
}
```

If the list is `[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1]` => `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

The fourth node should be 4 but instead get 1, why?
How can I fix this ?

Comment: the class and the function has no relation

Comment: You use JavaScript `Set` object to remove duplicates from an array, e.g.
`console.log([...new Set(arr)]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are checking the 2 adjacent nodes, it will miss other if those 2 adjacent nodes is not equal to each other, like the case `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]`

One solution is to have a set that check if the data has been visited

```
const removeDuplicates = (headNode) => {
  let cur = headNode;
  let visited = new Set([cur.data]);
  while (cur.next) {
    let nextnode = cur.next;
    if (visited.has(nextnode.data)) {
      // if current node data is visited, skip
      cur.next = nextnode.next;
    } else {
      // if current node data is not visited, visit
      visited.add(nextnode.data);
      cur = nextnode;
    }
  }
  return headNode;
};
```

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data = null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

const removeDuplicates = (headNode) => {
  let cur = headNode;
  let visited = new Set([cur.data]);
  while (cur.next) {
    let nextnode = cur.next;
    if (visited.has(nextnode.data)) {
      // if current node data is visited, skip
      cur.next = nextnode.next;
    } else {
      // if current node data is not visited, visit
      visited.add(nextnode.data);
      cur = nextnode;
    }
  }
  return headNode;
};

// prepare data
const arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1];
let head, prevNode;
while (arr.length > 0) {
  let node = new Node(arr.pop());
  if (prevNode) {
    node.next = prevNode;
  }
  head = node;
  prevNode = node;
}

// remove duplicate
const headAfterRemove = removeDuplicates(head);

// verify result
let cursor = headAfterRemove;
while (cursor) {
  console.log(cursor.data);
  cursor = cursor.next;
}
```